# C# Directory.GetFiles finds and counts a file that starts with ~$. How can I delete that file?

Tags: c#, windows

It seems I have a unwanted file in a directory. The file is an MS Word file, with a filename that begins with ~$, which I understand is a locked file, probably created by MS Word.  But, the file remains after MS Word is closed.

I have the Windows explorer setup to show hidden files, but it does now show this unwanted file, so I can't delete it.  Nor do I see it when using the command line.

C# Directory.GetFiles gets and counts this file, causing an incorrect file count.

I want to delete this file.  But I need to see it to delete it.  How can I get rid of this unwanted file?

Comment: Why not just count files that don't start with `~$`? Deleting the file is not on-topic here, ignoring it in code would be.

Comment: Showing hidden files should be enough for it display in explorer. Just delete them from a command prompt if it's really problematic. Also, if the files are sticking around after you close MS Word, you've got a problem.

Comment: Might have the system attributes set, which is different from the Hidden attribute. You’re really not supposed to touch those.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could ignore the files:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Where(name => !name.StartsWith("~$"));
```

Comment: How is 'ignoring' an alternative to 'deleting' ?

Comment: "C# Directory.GetFiles gets and counts this file, causing an incorrect file count."

Comment: @TaW deleting the file this time isn't a long term solution since whatever event caused the file creation could certainly happen again.

Answer (score 0):

The `~$` files are lock/recovery files that Word creates while you have a file actively open for editing. If you are **very sure** Word is not running **and** that it was shut down properly, you can safely delete these files. If it's possible Word was not shut down properly, you may still want these files in order to recover unsaved work.

> I have the Windows explorer setup to show hidden files, but it does now show this unwanted file

I can't reproduce this. I just verified on my own system that setting explorer to show hidden files did indeed show the `~$` file. Windows can remember these settings per-folder, so please check that you really do have explorer set to show hidden files for the appropriate folder.

If that fails, you can also try using [`Directory.GetFileSystemInfos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos), which will give you a class that includes both the name and an `Attributes` property you can use to filter out or show hidden files:

```
var files = Directory.GetFileSystemInfo("path here")
           .Where(fsi => fsi.Attributes != null && fsi.Attributes.Hidden && fsi.Name.StartsWith("~$"))
           .Select(fsi => fsi.FullName);
foreach(var file in files)
{
   File.Delete(file);
}
```

Comment: Sometimes a file lock does remain even after Word (or other applications) have closed. Sometimes a reboot helps, sometimes a tool like Unlocker does.